# How to get looping item count in collectionView numberOfItemsInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `NSMutableArray` as below:-

[image]

In my `UICollectionView` `numberOfItemsInSection`, how can i get item count for attribute_name? For example, under attribute_group_name `Color` section , I will get 4 items count.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.attributeGroupList[section].count;  //HOW CAN I GET ITEM COUNT FOR ATTRIBUTE_NAME?
}
```

UPDATED:-

Sample output with new data structure:-

```
 {
        "attribute_group_name" = Color;
        names =         (
            Black,
            White,
            Gold,
            Red
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Service;
        names =         (
            "Free Shipping",
            Insurance
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Telco;
        names =         (
            Digi,
            Maxis,
            Celcom
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Material;
        names =         (
            Wood
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Brand;
        names =         (
            Apple,
            Mi,
            Gome,
            HuaWei
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = RAM;
        names =         (
            4G,
            8G,
            16G
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Size;
        names =         (
            1200sqf,
            908sqf
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Location;
        names =         (
            "Petaling Jaya",
            "Kuala Lumpur",
            Ipoh
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Memory;
        names =         (
            32G,
            64G,
            128G,
            256G
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Warranty;
        names =         (
            "1 Year"
        );
    }
```

[image]
￼

Comment: Your dictionary is poorly designed.  Rather than having variable keys, you should have a single key, say `attributes` which is an array of `String`s or whatever.  Also please post text, not images

Comment: Hi Paulw11, will take note on post text instead of image. thx!

Answer (score 1):

If I look to your data structure I would say that:

```
self.attributeGroupList[section].count-1
```

the "-1" is here because it looks like your data structure only have one different key.
But I fill like this is not the answer you are waiting for.

The real problem here, is your data structure, I would definitely go that way instead:

```
{
 "group_name": Color;
 "names":["Black","White","Red"];
}
```

so that you can do something like that:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.attributeGroupList[section][@"names"].count;
}
```

EDIT:

Ok, so you are doing great, the only small thing to change is that part:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < groupNames.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *name = [[groupNames objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"attribute_name"];
        [entry setObject:name forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"attribute_name%d", i + 1]];
    }
```

Just need to do it that way, I'm sure there is a smarter way to do it, but here it's simple enough:

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *groups = [_filterItem valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.attribute_group_name"];
for (NSString *attribute_group_name_header in groups){
     NSMutableDictionary *entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];
     [entry setObject:attribute_group_name_header forKey:@"attribute_group_name"];

      NSArray *groupNames = [_filterItem filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute_group_name = %@", attribute_group_name_header]];
      NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray new];
      for (int i = 0; i < groupNames.count; i++){
           NSString *name = [[groupNames objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"attribute_name"];
           [names addObject: name];
      }
      [entry setObject: names forKey:@"names"];
      [resultArray addObject:entry];
}
```

EDIT 2:

After looking at your final object, it appears that I forgot to add "@" before "names" string. So make sure you have that before any string (the first EDIT has been corrected accordingly).

also, maybe add a string cast like that : `(NSString *)` before adding to the array `names`, like so:

```
 NSString *name = (NSString *)[[groupNames objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"attribute_name"];
```

This will give you an array of string, instead of an array of random objects (like you have at the moment), which can be difficult to use.

EDIT 3:

We can do it ahah.
Looks like it doesn't catch the key "names"
So you will need to be more specific. Something like that:

```
return ((NSArray *)[self.attributeGroupList[0] objectForKey:@"names"]).count
```

Keep in mind that this piece of code is really bad. I'm forcecasting an object into an array. It's an assumption and you should perform some tests on the object before doing that. Because if the structure of your data change, this will crash.

NOTE:

You are asking a lot of questions for one issue. Stackoverflow is all about solving one precise and well define question so that your question can be helpful to others. Here you definitely need assistance on your code generally speaking. So this is definitely not the place where to post this. I would recommend you to have a look to website like Codementor

Comment: Hi RomOne, may i know how to set data structure like your proposed solution?

Comment: Sure. From where do you get these data? Is it something you have set in your app, or is it something you get from an API?

Comment: Hi RomOne, please check my updated question on top. This is what I did the poor structure.

Comment: Sorry I think I clicked too quickly on a button, I may have wrongly edit your post. I'm not able to see your changes, could you add it back? thanks :)

Comment: Please try to review again. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, you added the edit in my answer instead of adding it in your question. That's fine, I've moved it to your answer. I post an edit of my answer soon

Comment: Thanks for your prompt action and help!

Comment: Hi RomOne, thanks for your solution and you missed out @ at [entry setObject: names forKey:@"names"];

Comment: I hit error  "Indexing expression is invalid because subscript type 'char *' is not an Objective-C pointer" in return attributeGroupList[section]["names"].count;. Any idea?

Comment: Interesting... could you print the content of your dictionary with the new structure. Just to see if it has the structure we want.

Comment: Hi RomOne, please take a look sample result as above.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot a "@" before the "names" string, see the updated answer

Comment: i hit another error here :- Property 'attributeGroupList' not found on object of type 'Filter_ViewController *'; did you mean to access instance variable 'attributeGroupList'? Any idea?

Comment: On the same line? Looks like it's coming from somewhere else in your code

Comment: Hi RomOne, please check my error screenshot on top. Yes, same line in   numberOfItemsInSection